# syntax error, unexpected identifier "count", expecting ":" Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, syntax

So I'm trying to make a total users count in laravel 9 but when I finished with it I got this error `syntax error, unexpected identifier "count", expecting ":"`

Here's the code `{{ return count(Schema::getColumnListing('users')); }}`

Comment: Where is above code is located? Model, controller or view?

Answer (score 0):

The error you’re seeing is thrown due to the return statement between the curly braces. You can fix this by simply removing the return statement:

```
{{ count(Schema::getColumnListing('users')); }}
```

However, `getColumnListing` returns an array of all columns found in the specified table, see `Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder.php`:

```php
/**
 * Get the column listing for a given table.
 *
 * @param  string  $table
 * @return array
 */
public function getColumnListing($table)
{
    $results = $this->connection->selectFromWriteConnection($this->grammar->compileColumnListing(
        $this->connection->getTablePrefix().$table
    ));

    return $this->connection->getPostProcessor()->processColumnListing($results);
}
```

To count the number of rows within a specified table you could access the DB object directly from a view, here is an example which counts the number of rows present from the users table:

```
{{ DB::table('users')->count(); }}
```

However, you may be encouraged to put this logic within a controller and pass the appropriate data to a view (see [the Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#running-database-queries)), for example:

#### UserController.php

```php
<?php
 
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
 
class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show a list of all of the application's users.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $numberOfUsers = DB::table('users')->count();
        return view('user.index', ['userCount' => $numberOfUsers]);
    }
}
```

#### index.blade.php (user.index)

```
<!-- template header goes here -->

<!-- display number of users in bold -->
We have <strong>{{ $userCount }}</strong> registered users!

<!-- template footer goes here -->
```

#### Models

Personally, for something like this (where you’re likely to have a User model) I would substitute using the DB object with using a Laravel model. This means the index function from UserController would look something like this:

```php
public function index()
{
    $numberOfUsers = \App\Models\User::all()->count();
    return view('user.index', ['userCount' => $numberOfUsers]);
}
```

Finally, you could simply call the model from the view:

```php
{{ \App\Models\User::count(); }}
```

Read more about models [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#introduction).

Comment: Alright so I did it, but it counted 9 columns in my users table even though theres 23. How do I fix this?

Comment: I've updated the answer, see the additional details and examples.